# Морфемный состав глагола «исчезать (исчезнуть)»

Tags: морфология, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, чередования

Исторически глагол *исчезнуть* родствен таким словам, как *исказить* и *проказа*, поэтому диахронически он должен члениться так: ис-чез-ну-ть (ис-чез-а-ть). Но как разобрать слово по составу в синхронии? Существует ли чередование *-чез-/-каз-*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синхронически - исчез/ну/ть

Основа исчез-непроизводная, нет родственных слов с корнем чез- (исчез, исчезновение)

Этимологически да,  анализ выявляет корень чез-, который обнаруживается в старинном слове чезнуть — исчезать, пропадать („Толковый словарь" В. Даля), в старославянском чезнути — пропадать, потухать. Корень чез- обычно сближается с корнем каз- (казаться). В чез/каз- усматривается чередование согласных ч — к и гласных е — а (ср. лезть — лазить). Исчезнуть значит „скрыться из виду".